# Invalid json from json_encode()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

This is my PHP file (The actual file is more complex but I found that it fails even with the simplest code):

```
<?php
$salida = array(1,2,3,4,5);
echo json_encode($salida);
?>
```

This is the response I get:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Seems to be valid, but it's not. My AJAX app says `'Unexpected token'` when I pass it to the jQuery.parseJSON() function. When I paste it to JSONLint web page, return the same error.

I notice that if I delete the first character and type it again, the JSON becomes valid.

This got me thinking and I checked the JSON string  with an HEX editor and I found strange characters at the beginning of the file:

```
ï»¿ï»¿[1,2,3,4,5]
```

This is strange because the function worked fine until a few days ago, and the file has not been modified.

The `<?php>` tag is at the beginning of the file and it's encoded as utf-8.

I work with XAMPP 1.8.3 on Windows 8.1. I reinstalled XAMPP just in case something is broken, but the `json_enconde()` function still not working.

Anyone knows how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the PHP file (and all files it's including) without an UTF8 BOM (byte order marker). How to do this depends on your editor. Note that using UTF8 itself is perfectly fine and encouraged. Just without the BOM.

Comment: In fact my file is encoded as UTF-8 without BOM but I noticed that one of the dependent files called with require_once() was encoded as UTF8 with BOM.